# How many ways I can put $k$ bishops on $n\times n$ chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Is there a formula how to count in how many ways I can put $k$ bishops on $n\times n$ chessboard such that no two bishops threaten each other?

Comment: The cases $k=2,\ldots,10$, $n=k$ and $n=2k$ as well as the sum over $k$ all have [their own OEIS sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=%20name%3a%22number%20of%20ways%20to%20place%22%20name%3abishops). The book *Non-attacking chess pieces* ([free PDF download](http://web.telecom.cz/vaclav.kotesovec/math.htm)) contains the relevant polynomials up to $k=10$ (beginning on p. $234$).

Comment: PDF now locates here: http://www.kotesovec.cz/math.htm but large parts are not in English.